# unexpected token '<' with react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get started with react and can't seem to get rid of the above console error. It does actually display 'Hello world' in the browser but something must be wrong to be getting this error. I've searched many solutions on here but none are working for me. I'm using visual studio 2022 and created a new web app with dot.net core with mvc views.

html:

```
<script  src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script  src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="~/js/site.js"></script>

<div id=site>
</div>
```

js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('site')
);
```

[image]

Comment: try assigning the h1 component to a variable and add that as the parameter instead of the plain html

Comment: @SeanLawton same issue: 
const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;

ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('site')
);

Comment: Just nitpicking: the id=site should be id='site'. Also, that error is because browser is unable to process the JSX syntax.